# Cannot enter in centOS with any user

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I am using **cent OS** Operating system without **GNOME**.

In the starting, it asks

```
localhost login:
Password:
```

It has one user named **service** under group name **service** whose password is also **service**.

I want to enter in OS by this user named **service**.

When I do this, it shows this lines

```
Last Login: Mon Feb 18 16:16:26 on tty1
-bash: /home/service/.bashrc: Permission denied
-bash-3.2$
```

I changed in **/etc/sudoers**, and add **service ALL=(ALL)  ALL**, right below **root ALL=(ALL)  ALL**, but it didn't work.

when I try to switch from root to service, it shows the same error.

**EDITED**

When I run `ls -a -l | grep .bashrc`, it shows

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root   41 Feb 18 11:40 .bashrc -> /home/service/etc/version.symlink/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 service service 124 Feb 15 13:06 .bashrc-moved-1361167832
```

Help me. Looking for your kind response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the output of your `ls -a -l | grep .bashrc` command, I guess you have to issue this command as root :

```
chown service:service /home/service/.bashrc
```

Comment: yes, it works, But when I run any shell script in this user named "service", it gives `Permission denied`. Why ?

Comment: when I run above ls command,  it gives the same output

Comment: Really very very thanks. Now my problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with sudo. Check the permissions on `/home/service/.bashrc` It should be owned by `service:service`. It should be also readable for that user.

`/home/service` itself should be owned by `service:service` and be have `rwx` rights for the owner and `rx` for the group.

Comment: I run `ls -a -l | grep .bashrc` , it gives output, I wrote that in question. Check EDITED part.